# show an image obtained from a web api in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a web api in asp net core:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetFileSystemStoreObject(string id)
    {
        var archivo = await _context.FileSystemStoreObject.FindAsync(id);

        if (archivo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
         ...
        var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead(rutaArchivo);
        return File(image, "image/jpeg");

    }
```

And from my react application I want to show the image. But I do not know how to do it.
I have tried the following in react, but it doesn't work.

```
function NoticiaFoto({url}) {

    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

    let ruta = 'https://localhost:44357/api/filesystemstoreobjects/'  + url;

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(ruta)
            .then(res => res.json())
                .then(
                    (result) => {
                        setIsLoaded(true);
                        setItem(result);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        setIsLoaded(false);
                        setError(error);
                    }
            )
    }, [])


    return(
        <div><img src={item} alt= "foto" /></div>
    )

}
export default NoticiaFoto
```

I have tested the API and it works fine.

What I don't know is how to get the image from react and display it on screen.

Please help.

Comment: try with height and width attribute of img element set to some value

Comment: What is the "result" data comes from fetch ? base64, arrayBuffer etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine when you assign computed `url` to `src` prop.

```js
const NoticiaFoto = ({id}) => {
  const url = `https://localhost:44357/api/filesystemstoreobjects/${id}`;

  return <div>
    <img src={url} alt= "foto" />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NoticiaFoto id={1} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The best way to go about this is to form a URL that accesses the file from your server via FTP.

```
let image_url = "http://server_address/your_public_folder/file_name";



return(
        <div><img src={image_url} alt= "foto" /></div>
    )
```